# solution of the differential riccati matrix equation in optimal control

Tags: matrices, control-theory, optimal-control

I have a problem with the differential Riccati matrix equation in optimal control. 
As we all know, for a cost function
  $J = \frac{1}{2}x(t_f)^T S_f x(t_f) + \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t_f}(x^T Q x + u^T R u) dt$ ; if we set Q , $S_f$  are seimi-positive definite, R is positive. Then, the  solution of the  differential Riccati matrix equation
$ -\dot{P} = PA + A^T P - P B R^{-1} B^T P + Q $  should be semi-positive definite. 
Is there any conditions to guarantee a positive definite solution of above equation.